# DotNetNuke Navigation Menu Anchors Target=_top

Tags: internet-explorer, dotnetnuke

how can i give target=_top for all the menu items in the navigation menu of a dotnet nuke website?
or
how can give code from my page to make sure all anchors will open in the top frame.
i have previously used  and it works for Firefox, and google chrome, but not Internet Explorer.
i need it to work on internet explorer!

thanks in advance!

Comment: i solved my problem, i came up with a work around!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the DarkKnight skin you can modify the DDRMenu templates, you will likely find them in the /portals/_default/skins/DarkKnight folder then dnnmega and dnnstandard folders, and then there is an XSLT file in there that you can customize.

For the DNNMega menu you'll find

```
<a href="{@url}">
```

in which you can modify and add target="_top"

Another approach might be to have jquery go through and do it on the page load, the jquery you use for that though will vary greatly by the Menu you are using in your skin.